# Como cifrar una cadena de caracteres en linux

Tags: linux, powershell, encriptación

Estoy buscando como encriptar una cadena de Strings en linux para su posterior uso en otros scripts a través de variables de entorno, deseo hacer algo parecido a powershell donde:

```
# Se convierte el password recibido como texto plano en SecureString
$SecureString = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "M1P@ssw0rd"

# Se convierte el SecureString en una cadena estandar cifrada que se puede guardar para su posterior uso
$StandardString = ConvertFrom-SecureString $SecureString

# Se guarda la cadena estandar cifrada en una variable de entorno
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("passq", "$StandardString", "Machine")


# Se guarda el contenido encriptado de la variable de entorno en una nueva variable
$variable = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("passq", "Machine")

# Se hace un reverso de la cadena estandar cifrada a SecureString
$passwordencry = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $variable

# Se realiza la reconversión de SecureString a texto plano
$passwordencry = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($passwordencry)
$passwordencry = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($passwordencry)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar PowerShell desde Linux.

Te comparto la documentación para instalar PowerShell en Linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2

Otra opción es usando la librería de OpenSSL, por ejemplo:

#### encode.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $1 | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:somepassword
```

#### decode.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $1 | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pass pass:somepassword
```

#### Hacer archivos ejecutables

```
chmod +x encode.sh decode.sh
```

#### Ejemplo de cifrado

```
./encode.sh "this is my test string"
# => U2FsdGVkX18fjSHGEzTXU08q+GG2I4xrV+GGtfDLg+T3vxpllUc/IHnRWLgoUl9q
```

#### Ejemplo de descifrado

```
./decode.sh U2FsdGVkX18fjSHGEzTXU08q+GG2I4xrV+GGtfDLg+T3vxpllUc/IHnRWLgoUl9q
# => this is my test string
```

Esta solución la encontré aquí --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718005/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-text-in-shell-linux-environment

¡Espero que esto ayude!